# Optimize group by used along with where condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, myisam, database-optimization

I have a table with around 8M rows and 35 columns(1G in size overall). This is used for reporting that involves multi-level `group by` conditions. Here is one such query.

```
explain select min(a), max(a), avg(a), sum(b) from test where (c=2 or c=20 or c=18 or c=21 or c=12) and d>='2013-01-01' and d <= '2013-12-01' group by c,e;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
    table: test
     type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
      key: PRIMARY
  key_len: 7
      ref: NULL
     rows: 154911
    Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This takes around 1.8 sec to execute. Primary key is on `c,d` and is getting used in evaluating where clause. The `count(*)` query with the same where condition and without group by returns around 150000 rows. So rows scanned in the actual query is also OK. But, none of the indexes is getting used in grouping of the results. I have tried putting index on `c` and `c,e`.

My question is, can another index be used for sorting/grouping once where condition has been applied and result set is in tmp table.

I have allocated enough memory to `tmp_table_size`. So, tmp table is not going to disk surely.  The table is using `MyISAM`.

Comment: FWIW, I prefer \G for EXPLAIN

Comment: Your query references a table alias `d` (`d.effective_date`) that is not defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : sry man.. effective date remained there as a mistake... i have edited the query to make more sense.

Comment: How many rows does this query return?

Comment: Note about your query on dates.  If you intended to do the entire year (up to Dec 31, 2013), and your transaction records have TIME portions to the date/time field, then this will NOT include all Dec 31 data as Dec 31, 2013 at 3:15 in the morning is greater than Dec 31, 2013 at 12:00 morning.  You should consider LESS than Jan 1, 2014 so it gets all the way up to Dec 31 at 11:59:59pm.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: around 20

Comment: @DRapp : thanks for the observation.. but in my case d is a date field and all the date values contain only the first date of the month... it's the ORM that is putting the time field.. but that wont have an effect on performance i guess

Comment: So noted, but something that many may never realize and wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

If you make an index using (c, d , e , a , b) then the performance will be faster. This will be a covering index and the table scan will not be done as is being done now.

Also, I am just curious, can you give me some pointers about the effective_month functionality you are using ?

Also, One important thing is the index size. The maximum number of indexes per table and the maximum index length is defined per storage engine. You can read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html). In your case it will not be a issue as you are dealing with I am assuming dates and numbers. Its just that the Insert's will be slower.

Comment: i didn't want to put the actual query.. effective date remained there as a mistake.. please look at the query now.. 
creating index on (c, d , c , e , a , b) is what your suggestion will turn into i think... but we can't put same column multiple times in an index... can we?

Comment: Please look at it now. I have modified the answer.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. i tried this.. but performance worsened and rows scanned count ballooned to 450000... in any case, this query is not my only use case, and i don't i can create too many composite indexes for my every use case

Comment: can  u run optimize table <tablename> after running this query ? chk the performance then and pls let me knw too.

Comment: tried that.. no change... the rows of my table don't get updated at all.. we periodically do truncate and insert all the rows again.. so optimize table shouldn't have given performance boost

Answer (score 0):

A covering index might help.  Assuming this is your query:

```
select min(a), max(a), avg(a), sum(b)
from test
where (c=2 or c=20 or c=18 or c=21 or c=12) and
      d >= '2013-01-01' and d <= '2013-12-01'
group by c, e;
```

The covering index would be `test(c, d, e, a, b)`.

It is, however, very difficult to get rid of the file sort in MySQL aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

In any SQL, for any reason if there are multiple scans to be performed on only one table, we can use one index for either of them but not both.

EX: Your query needs

1. One scan to process the where clause data.(INDEX1: index on c, d is useful)
2. One scan to sort the result set for group by operation.(INDEX2: index on c, e is useful)

If the number of rows in the result set is more, better add the INDEX2 so that sort would be quick.
If the number of rows in the result set is less, better add the INDEX1 so that where clause would be processed quick.